# running a MFC C++ code in VIsual Studio error NewFolder is not a valid working directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, image-processing, mfc

Its an Application that demonstrates the basics of using the Microsoft
Foundation Classes

****When I run the code, The message box pops up from visual studio that

                                                                                                  Unable to start the program C:\Users\Sushma\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Pooja\Debug\Pooja.exe
C:\Users\Sushma\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\NewFolder is not a valid working directory.
But no such NewFolder exists in the project folder.****

This file contains a summary of what you will find in each of the files that
make up your Pooja application.

Pooja.vcxproj
    This is the main project file for VC++ projects generated using an application wizard.
    It contains information about the version of Visual C++ that generated the file, and
    information about the platforms, configurations, and project features selected with the
    application wizard.

Pooja.vcxproj.filters
    This is the filters file for VC++ projects generated using an Application Wizard. 
    It contains information about the association between the files in your project 
    and the filters. This association is used in the IDE to show grouping of files with
    similar extensions under a specific node (for e.g. ".cpp" files are associated with the
    "Source Files" filter).

Pooja.h
    This is the main header file for the application.  It includes other
    project specific headers (including Resource.h) and declares the
    CPoojaApp application class.

Pooja.cpp
    This is the main application source file that contains the application
    class CPoojaApp.

Pooja.rc
    This is a listing of all of the Microsoft Windows resources that the
    program uses.  It includes the icons, bitmaps, and cursors that are stored
    in the RES subdirectory.  This file can be directly edited in Microsoft
    Visual C++. Your project resources are in 1033.

res\Pooja.ico
    This is an icon file, which is used as the application's icon.  This
    icon is included by the main resource file Pooja.rc.

res\Pooja.rc2
    This file contains resources that are not edited by Microsoft
    Visual C++. You should place all resources not editable by
    the resource editor in this file.

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

The application wizard creates one dialog class:

PoojaDlg.h, PoojaDlg.cpp - the dialog
    These files contain your CPoojaDlg class.  This class defines
    the behavior of your application's main dialog.  The dialog's template is
    in Pooja.rc, which can be edited in Microsoft Visual C++.

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Other Features:

ActiveX Controls
    The application includes support to use ActiveX controls.

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Other standard files:

StdAfx.h, StdAfx.cpp
    These files are used to build a precompiled header (PCH) file
    named Pooja.pch and a precompiled types file named StdAfx.obj.

Resource.h
    This is the standard header file, which defines new resource IDs.
    Microsoft Visual C++ reads and updates this file.

Pooja.manifest
    Application manifest files are used by Windows XP to describe an applications
    dependency on specific versions of Side-by-Side assemblies. The loader uses this
    information to load the appropriate assembly from the assembly cache or private
    from the application. The Application manifest  maybe included for redistribution
    as an external .manifest file that is installed in the same folder as the application
    executable or it may be included in the executable in the form of a resource.

Comment: Please remove all irrelevant information. There's no need to describe what every file does. Then add relevant information: the problem is in running the application, what is in Project Properties->Configuration Properties->Debugging? Maybe it's just a problem with spaces in the paths and you need to quote the command/arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your project's property page (Project Menu - Properties), click on the the "Debugging" tab and check to see if "Working Directory" has been set to something strange (with NewFolder in it). The default value is $(ProjectDir)